# Should I rebuild my PHP website with a document database in order to improve performance?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, hbase

We have a website developed in PHP with MySQL and sometimes facing problems when traffic increases. We have almost optimized the site in all ways to handle more requests but still facing problems at peak hours.

One of my friends suggests to rebuild the site using HBase / MongoDB as back-end to improve the performance. Also he suggests that if we rebuild it, we can easily move to cloud services. But we need to learn entire thing and redevelop it.

Is it better idea to do so?

Comment: Anyone who suggests anything other than profiling, has no clue. Avoid such "advisors" at any cost. Did you profile your site? What kind of server it works on?

Comment: We did not profile my website till now. We just followed some optimization tips. Please suggest me the tools to profile.

Comment: when u say traffic increases - can you be more specific ?

Comment: First of all you have to use `Firebug` addon for Firefox, "Net" tab. To see whole page performance, including css, images, js files etc. then, if you discover that it's PHP slowest of them all, you have to use either `xdebug` or manual profiling using microtime(1), see example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454161/benchmarking-php-page-load-times/2454267#2454267

Comment: what - no throw more hardware at it ?? seriously, if your app doesnt scale from conception then you have issues so maybe a re-write is in order but dont just add layers of complexity and indirection to it - it will just get more resource intensive and less scaleable. Fix the design not the implementation!

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to do is to profile your web app to determine what the bottleneck is.

If it's definitely queries to the database, then replacing mysql with mongodb *might* be a good idea, but document databases work in a different way to relational ones, and you might have trouble porting some types of functionality. If you do decide to try mongo, prototype early and often, because there's no garuantee it will be faster for you.

If scalability really is a problem for you, then why not jump straight into a cloud-based web architecture like google app engine. This is java or python and document database (bigtable) based, but forces you into a scalable "cloud" architecture from the very beginning.

Another option is to simply introduce (or optimise) caching (with memcache) - this will have less architectural effect on your application therefore take less effort.

Comment: We use LAMP. We did not profile my website till now. We just followed some optimization tips. Please suggest me the tools to profile.

Comment: I've not actually tried to profile any LAMP systems before, maybe ask another question on stack overflow? You'd probably need different tools for apache, mysql, the server's CPU, the server's network access etc.

Comment: And depending on what you mean by "problems", maybe you need to profile from a browser too, such as with firebug. +1 to col shrapnel

Answer (score 0):

There are simple MySql scalability options out there too.  Back in the "dark days", we'd just throw dedicated hardware at the DB as step one, more recently, clustering became possible.  There's also cloud-type solutions that are MySQL based you could use.  For instance, Amazon's RDS claims to work with all the same commands as MySQL and also claims to be an easy conversion.

Before you get down to all that, I'd recommend optimizing, indexing, and profiling.  I've run PHP/MySQL CMS-based sites with 1 million+ uniques a day with no need to go to the cloud.  The code is the key.

Comment: Throwing more hardware can still be a fine solution.

Comment: it's a great solution for incompetence - agreed.